# 'punch out' effect on NSAttributedString on a UITextView

Tags: uitextview, mask, nsattributedstring

Is it possible to add a custom attribute so that I can have a background fill around certain text ranges but with the foreground of that text being "punched out" (is this a mask) out of the background color?

If it's not possible from a custom attribute approach, is it possible in another way by overriding UITextView or something?

Thanks for any pointers!

[image: what I'm looking for]

Comment: Maybe with CoreText. It seems not simple. Could you provide an visual exemple of what you want?

Comment: I've attached a sample of the effect I'm looking for @Larme. The background in my app is actually a gradient so I can't just set the foreground to match the background easily.